# How can I search in the Matlab command window for things named with an underscore?

Tags: search, matlab

Matlab 2013a can't seem to search in the command window. Example:

I called two functions `NLSCN` and `NLSCN_FAST`. But when searching inside the command window, I was able to find the first, and not the second. The moment I hit the underscore key, it shows me that nothing matches my search.

What can I do?

Comment: I previously had the same issue. However, it does work in Matlab R2016a, I think they must have fixed it in a newer version somewhere.